# Pyspark: how to filter by date and read parquet files which is partitioned by date

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet, database-partitioning

I have a huge dataset of partitioned parquet files stored in AWS s3 in `data-store/year=<>/month=<>/day=<>/hour=<>/` folder format. e.g `data-store/year=2020/month=06/day=01/hour=05`.

I want to read the files only for a specific date range e.g `2020/06/01 to 2020/08/30` or something like all the records with a date greater than equal to `2020/06/01`.

How to do this effectively so that only the required data is loaded to the spark memory.

Comment: You can try reading in the file paths 'data-store/year=2020/month=06/', 'data-store/year=2020/month=07/' and 'data-store/year=2020/month=08/'

Comment: Each month data is of 200 gb. let say if I want read from 2020/07/30 to 2020/09/05 then for month 07 and month 09 unnecessarily all the data will be loaded.

Comment: Then you can use 'data-store/year=2020/month=07/day=30/', 'data-store/year=2020/month=07/day=31/', 'data-store/year=2020/month=08/', 'data-store/year=2020/month=09/day=01/', etc.

Comment: fine. Intially I thought of doing that i.e generating a list using a program. But I had a hunch that there might be some other efficient way